# Как убрать область виджета?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress, тема *MH Magazine*, версия 1.8.6.

Я убрал с правой панели с определенных станиц виджеты (области). Всё хорошо, но сама область осталась, и визуально это некрасиво - страница как бы смещена влево от центра.

Как полностью убрать область виджета?

Comment: попробовали через тепмплейт редактор?

Answer (score 2):

Смотри в WP то, что вы называете областью называется сайдбаром(sidebar).
В некоторых темах есть возможность отключать их из админки или поменяв шаблон страницы. В других нужно залезать в редактор шаблонов и править ручками. В этом случае вас должны интересовать элементы .mh-sidebar попробуйте скрыть или отключить их программно.